# Get value between unknown string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to pull out a string between 2 other strings. But to make it more complicated the proceeding contents will often differ.

[image]

The string I'm trying to retrieve is **Christchurch**.

The regex I have so far is `(?<=300px">).*(?=</td)` and it will pull out the string I'm looking fine but it will also return dozens of other strings through out the LARGE text file I'm searching.

What I'd like to do is limit the prefix to start seraching from **Office:**, all the way to **300px">** but, the contents **between** those 2 strings will sometimes differ dependant upon user preferences.

To put it in crude non regex terms I want to do the following: Starting at `Office:` all the way to `300px>` find the string that starts here and ends with `</td`. Thus resulting in **Christchurch**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the posts from adamdc78 and greg I have the been able to come up with the below regex. This is exactly what I needed.

Thanks for you help.

```
(?<=office.*\n.*300px">).*(?=<\/td)
```

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow: you should accept their answers (since they helped) and not add a *thank you answer*

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using the HTMLAgilityPack instead? It's a Nuget package for handling HTML which is able to handle malformed HTML pretty well. Most on Stack Overflow would recommend against using Regex for HTML - see here: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Here's how you'd do it for your example:

```
using HtmlAgilityPack; //This is a nuget package!
var html = @"<tr >
               <td align=""right"" valign=""top""><strong>Office:</strong>&nbsp; </td>
               <td align=""left"" class=""stippel"" style=""white-space: wrap;max-width:300px"">Christchurch </td>
             </tr>";

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var node = htmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='stippel']");
Console.WriteLine(node.InnerHtml);
```

I haven't tested this code but it should do what you need.

Comment: The advantage to this is that you can probably look for the tag with your class in it and just pull out its value.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're encountering is that `*` is greedy.  Use the lazy/reluctant version `*?`.

```
Office:[\s\S]*?300px">(.*?)</td
```

This solution uses a group match rather than look-arounds.

Comment: That will not help. As mentioned in the post that regex '(?<=300px">).*(?=</td)' works and it does return Christchurch, but in the text file I have 40Kb it is also returning hundreds of other results that match. I want to start searching from Office [any and all characters all the way through] 300px and THEN retrieve the value.

Comment: Still not exactly what I'm looking for. The revised regex returns **everything** from Office to <td, inclusive.

Comment: I've included a link to a screenshot of the html code I'm working with. I could not attach a picture because my rep is too low.

Comment: It will match everything, but the first group will be the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need something like this:

```
office.*\n.*|(?<=300px">).*(?=<\/td)
```

Comment: Similar to the answer offered by adamdc78 this is not exactly what I want. I only want to retrieve the string **Christchurch**.

Comment: **Starting at Office: all the way to 300px> find the string that starts here and ends with </td** what does that mean?

Comment: Can you not see the source code in my initial post?

Comment: I can't see how this doesn't work with you! doesn't it retrieve only **Christchurch**  ? I re-checked your initial post and I don't see where you stuck now

Comment: I've included a link to a screenshot of the html code I'm working with. I could not attach a picture because my rep is too low.